# Error: This revision of snap "codium" was published using classic confinement

Tags: debian, snap

Whenever I try to install vs codium from snap I get this warning message:

```
  error: This revision of snap "codium" was published using classic confinement
       and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security
       sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at
       risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including
       --classic.
```

I do my best to use open source software since they are more private and secure.

This is the first time i get such warning.

My question is, what does that warning mean and is vs codium safe to use in general ?

Do i need to worry ?

Also why it is not available on Debian main repository to install through apt ? and when will it be ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the benefits that snaps bring to the table is a [confinement model](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) that traditional (e.g. Debian) packages don't generally have. By default, under "strict" confinement, a snap can do literally nothing other than read/write to/from a few specific directories. It can't hit the network, it can't read anything private, and so on. You poke small little holes in the confinement by using [interfaces](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interfaces). One will get you access to X11. Another will get you access to the webcam. Another will get you access to the network, and so on. These can be individually connected/disconnected by the user, a bit like Android permissions if you're familiar with that.

"Classic" confinement, on the other hand, virtually means "unconfined." This is the same as having no confinement at all, kind of like the average Debian package. When installing packages that require this level of access, snapd requires you the user to specifically opt into it by using the `--classic` flag.

This does not imply that codium is not safe to use, but simply that it's not confined. How you use that knowledge is up to you. It's not unusual for things like IDEs to be unconfined, simply because they require pretty wide access to the system in order to do what they do.

**Big caveat**: I'm saying all this assuming you're on an operating system that provides everything that the snapd confinement model requires (e.g. an up-to-date apparmor, seccomp filters, and so on), like Ubuntu. I don't actually think Debian does, which means snap confinement there isn't complete at all.

> Also why it is not available on Debian main repository to install through apt ? and when will it be ?

Probably simply because no one has packaged it yet, or perhaps you're not on a new enough release to have it in the repos.